# Tkinter not running program

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

```py
from tkinter import *

def raise_frame(frame):
    frame.tkraise()

root = Tk()

f1 = Frame(root)
f2 = Frame(root)
f3 = Frame(root)
f4 = Frame(root)

for frame in (f1, f2, f3, f4):
    frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='news')

Button(f1, text='Go to frame 2', command=lambda:raise_frame(f2)).pack()
Label(f1, text='FRAME 1').pack()

Label(f2, text='FRAME 2').pack()
Button(f2, text='Go to frame 3', command=lambda:raise_frame(f3)).pack()

Label(f3, text='FRAME 3').pack(side='left')
Button(f3, text='Go to frame 4', command=lambda:raise_frame(f4)).pack(side='left')

Label(f4, text='FRAME 4').pack()
Button(f4, text='Goto to frame 1', command=lambda:raise_frame(f1)).pack()

raise_frame(f1)
root.mainloop
```

I was able to run other code but this one wouldn't load I don't know why.

Comment: You forgot your `()` after `root.mainloop`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last statement isn't calling `mainloop` — it should be:

```
...
raise_frame(f1)
root.mainloop()  # Note `()` at end.
```

Comment: Oops, I should have read the answers before commenting!

Comment: @RufusVSL You can delete your comments…

Comment: I tend to leave my mistakes on file as a humbling cautionary tale for myself and others.